# Why is /proc/irq/*/smp_affinity showing too wide of mask for number of CPUs on my computer?

Tags: ubuntu

I am running X86_64 Ubuntu Desktop 15.04 with latest kernel (i.e. 3.19.0-22-generic). I was inspecting the interrupts and IRQs and noticed that the bit-mask for smp_affinity was twice as large as it should be and I am wondering why it is so?

But, more explicitly:

```
$ cat /proc/interrupts
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       
  0:         21          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:        113       1780        107         90  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  8:          0          1          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:        455       1106         71         57  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:      10768     131886       9077       7920  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
...
```

And then for example:

```
$ cat /proc/irq/0/smp_affinity
ff
$ cat /proc/irq/8/smp_affinity
0f
$ cat /proc/irq/47/smp_affinity
04
```

I was expecting to see only `1` digit instead of `2`. For example, in `IRQ 0`, I was expecting to see '`f`' instead of '`ff`'. The reason being is that I have only `4` CPUs per the first code listing and a mask of `4` bits would be sufficient to cover them. That is, '`1111`' would cover all `4` CPUs and hence `IRQ 0` would be '`f`'. Would someone know whether this is a bug or, does '`ff`' make sense and so, could someone explain to me?

Also, notice how in `IRQ 8` is '`0f`' which in the context of my `4` CPUs mean that all `4` of them would be targeted by that interrupt. If that is the case, then this is exactly like with `IRQ 0` which also covers all CPUs (`4` in total). In other terms '`0f`' is equivalent to '`ff`' which does not make sense to me :(

Any kind of explanation or guidance where to look further would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of the affinity bitmask depends on the number of *supported* CPUs in your kernel, not on the number of CPUs actually present in your system; at runtime though, only the bits corresponding to a CPU present are taken into account. See [`IRQ-affinity.txt`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt) and [`cpumask.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/cpumask.h) in the kernel source code for details.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I had a look at the `cpumask.h`and notice some info about possible, and present. I went to look in `sysfs` file and there it was mentioned at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/`those parameters. In my case, there are 4 present (0-3) while it is possible to have (0-7). So, this explains why the bitmask would be as long as it is. However, how can the kernel know how many "possible CPUs" there could be? `lscpu` and other commands are showing 4 CPUs. But, it could be that these commands are basing themselves from the same source as for `sysfs`. Would you know?

Comment: The number of supported CPUs is `NR_CPUS` in the kernel, and that's initialised to whatever value is given to `CONFIG_NR_CPUS` in the configuration (see [`threads.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/threads.h)).